# Displaying all selected data

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc-4

Everytime a user add a certain employee using a dropdownlist, It will be added and displayed. Here is my code.

```
<p id="employeeData"></p>
<center>
    @Html.DropDownList("employee")
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="insertNew();" />
</center>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function insertNew() {
        var emp_data = [];
        //getting the selected value
        var emp_name = document.getElementById("employee");
        var selected_value = emp_name.options[emp_name.selectedIndex].value;
        var selected_text = emp_name.options[emp_name.selectedIndex].text;
        // getting the id where to show the output
        var messageBox = document.getElementById("employeeData");

        emp_data.push(selected_text);
        messageBox.innerHTML = "";
        messageBox.innerHTML += " " + emp_data + "<br/>";
    }
</script>
```

But then, the output I was expecting was not achieve. Only the current selected data will be displayed and the previous one was replaced.

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `emp_data` array only contains one item (the current selection). Instead just append the `selected_text` to the element with `id="employeeData"` (don't clear the existing html using `messageBox.innerHTML = "";`)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Comment: And why do you have `var selected_value = ..`? (you never use it) And there is no reason to add the `selected_text` to an array first.

Comment: I was planning to store into a variable the value of the selected dropdown cuz im going to save all the selected data into the database

Comment: Your really going about this the wrong way. You should just have a checkboxlist of all employees strongly bound to your model and no javascript is required.

Comment: But we have thousands of employees

Comment: You have a dropdownlist with thousands of items? You probably need to reconsider that:)

Comment: I was thinking it would be more comfortable using dropdownlist than checkbox.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. It really helps a lot.